# Backup on an empty SSAS database hangs

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssis, ssas

I created an SSIS package to iterate through all databases on an SSAS instance. It grabs the DatabaseId using AMO in a vbscript, then generates the XMLA to backup each database.

Most databases backup with no problems, but when the ForEach gets to one particular database, the Execute Analysis Services DDL Task seems to hang. The .abf file is created, but the SSIS package doesn't seem to get the response that the command is completed. It's like the backup process is stuck on the file.

When I backup the database using SSMS dialogs, the same problem occurs. I verified that other databases backup successfully using this method.

I should note that the database in question is 0.0MB in "estimated" size according to the db properties in SSMS. Is the database truly empty, or could this be a sign of corruption?

**Why doesn't the backup process complete?** I get no error messages, just a long-running process that does not end. Is there anything I can do to find the root cause?

Comment: I should mention that I am new to SSAS so I'm not very familiar with any admin-level checks I can do.

Comment: Maybe talk to the owner of that database and see if it can be recreated? Might be a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backup hangs because the SSAS database is corrupt, which was the result of a forced reboot of the server.

Some questions this raises:

If an SSAS database has an estimated size of 0, does that always indicate a corrupted database?
Are there any other ways to detect SSAS db corruption by using SSMS dialogs or AMO?

Comment: Please ask a new question to address your follow-up questions. The format on Stack Exchange is geared for one-issue-per-question. You'll get more attention that way anyway. Thanks.

Comment: If you are seeing 0 MB, then yes, it's likely that your SSAS db wasn't processed correctly (some error). You should redeploy it. A simple check to verify your db is online would be to browse the cubes/dimensions in the SSMS. But I agree with @JonSeigel, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I included the additional questions because they build on the answer/solution, but I don't expect to have them answered as part of this question. I just felt like it's an incomplete answer without including them. If I post the question(s) separately on SE, I will edit w/ the links.

Comment: And yes, when I tried browsing the cube and other objects within the corrupted database using SSMS, the entire database appeared to be empty.