# How to check the health of a SSAS database? And of its backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, ssas

regarding backups of the SSAS databses, based on the following behaviour:

[Backup on an empty SSAS database hangs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43012/backup-on-an-empty-ssas-database-hangs?rq=1)

Is there a way to check whether or not the SSAS backup is healthy?

I would accept powershell, AMO, anything, any tool to get this done.

Plus after backing it up, how would I know that the backup file is not corrupted as well?

If yes, then is there a way to fix it, without rebuilding the cubes from scratch?

Our cubes here take a whole lot of processing and time to get rebuild, I am trying to figure it out a way to avoid that, in case the of a disaster recovery scenario.

I found the same question below, but I could not make it work. If at least there would be an example.

[How to verify a SSAS Backup and how to perform Integrity Checks in SSAS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83994/how-to-verify-a-ssas-backup-and-how-to-perform-integrity-checks-in-ssas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can verify an SSAS database isn't corrupt apart from querying it. If you query it and you get errors it's corrupt.

If your database ends up corrupt the only sure way to recover is to restore the last known good backup, even though sometimes you can get away with messing in the `.xml` files or the data folder structure there is no guarantee and it's certainly not automated.

You can test an OLAP backup using `msmdsrv.exe` on the server (located in `<driveletter>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance>\OLAP\bin`).

For example executing

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\bin>msmdsrv -j -b "f:\backup\olap\olap.abf"
```

on the server I'm currently on yields this:

> Backup file f:\backup\olap\olap.abf contains database with the Name
>   of OLAP and  Id of OLAP consisting of 179 files with the total size of
>   100632864 bytes All files were successfully tested

If you are using encryption you need to use the `-k` switch to provide the password

If the backup is invalid I don't know of any automated method to fix it apart from creating a new backup.