# Verify SSAS Backup returning arguments instead of expected output

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssas

Following the link [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210119182507/http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2008/09/13/ssas-verifying-backups.aspx) I tried to verify ssas backup and executed below mentioned command in specified path as in link.

```
msmdsrv -j -b "\\path\ssasfile.abf"
```

But all it outputs is the arguments I passed in:

```
 -j -b \\path\ssasfile.abf
```

However, I was expecting output as mentioned in the post [How to check the health of a SSAS database? And of its backups?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110790/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-ssas-database-and-of-its-backups). Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's what happens when you pass in a backup file that either doesn't exist or on which you don't have access.

For example if I run the command on an existing backup file I get this:

```
msmdsrv -j -b "c:\temp\AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE.abf"
```

Outputs the arguments as well as the test results:

> -j -b c:\temp\AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE.abf
>
> Backup file \?\c:\temp\AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE.abf
>   contains database with the Name of
>   AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE and Id of 
>   AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE consisting of 7927 files with the
>   total size of 5554858464 bytes 
>   All files were successfully tested

You can see the output starts with the arguments and then shows the test results.

If you point msmdsrv.exe to a non existing backup file it just returns the arguments and no results (unfortunately no error message either)

```
msmdsrv -j -b "c:\temp\NOTEXISTING.abf"
```

simply returns

> -j -b c:\temp\NOTEXISTING.abf

Comment: \\path\ssasfile.abf was just an example. I am sure i am passing existing backupfile and has access to the path

Comment: @PramodMaharjan I'm not sure if it's your account that needs access or the service account for Analysis services

Comment: Provided access to network service as well but couldn't make it work. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @PramodMaharjan what account had network share access? The SSAS Service account of your account?